# Why the squares doesn't appear in this socket.io html file?

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I want to create a .io game. So, an alternative to pubnub is hosting a broadcast server in http://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com/ . This server send the `socket.emit("msg")` to all clients connected to this server, but... the game is going pretty bad. The cube doesn't appear an it's giving me a strange error, so there is my code:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="464161591015-669suu0sat7n9c1lq2g6b3mn174g5sej.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px"class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
k=[]
obj={}
onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}
socket=io("http://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com/")
onSignIn=(googleUser)=>{
 c=document.createElement("canvas")
 document.body.style.margin=0
 document.body.appendChild(c)
 ctx=c.getContext("2d")
 profile=googleUser.getBasicProfile()
 console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()) // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
 console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName())
 console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl())
 console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()) // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
 emailID=profile.getId()
 username=profile.getName()
 imgURL=profile.getImageUrl()
 x=Math.floor(Math.random()*10-5)*128
 y=Math.floor(Math.random()*10-5)*128
 render=()=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  c.width=innerWidth
  c.height=innerHeight
  socket.emit("msg",{
   id:emailID,
   username:username,
   imgURL:imgURL,
   x:x,y:y  
  })
  if(k[37]){x-=5}
  if(k[38]){y-=5}
  if(k[39]){x+=5}
  if(k[40]){y+=5}
  for(x2=Math.floor((x-32*40)/32)*32-x+innerWidth/2-16;x2<innerWidth;x2+=32){
   for(y2=Math.floor((y-32*40)/32)*32-y+innerHeight/2-16;y2<innerHeight;y2+=32){
    ctx.lineWidth=4
    ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(200,200,200,1)"
    ctx.strokeRect(x2,y2,32,32)
   }
  }
  for(i in obj){
   img=document.createElement("img")
   img.src=obj[i].imgURL
   ctx.drawImage(img,obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2-64-16,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2-64-16,128,128)
   ctx.lineWidth=4
   ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)"
   ctx.strokeRect(obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2-64-16,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2-64-16,128,128)
  }
 }

 render()

 socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
   obj[e.id]={
    username:e.username,
    imgURL:e.imgURL,
    x:e.x,y:e.y
   }
 })
}
</script>
```

And this is the error:

```
undefined:1 GET http://drwerenverlivitz.atspace.cc/game.io/undefined 404 (Not Found)
```

So... what can I do?

Comment: This is far too broad a question, not sure why it's got 4 upvotes. What troubleshooting have you done to narrow down the problem? 404 error seems like an obvious place to start!

Comment: If we check the error, we can see that it's trying to get http://drwerenverlivitz.atspace.cc/game.io/undefined, so there may be an error in your redirection

Comment: Bu the way, as you io http://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com, can we see the code you put in there?

Comment: The code of chat is this:

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.1.1/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
name=prompt("Enter your name.")
socket=io('https://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com/')
socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
  d.innerHTML+=e.data+"<br>"
})
document.onkeydown=()=>{
  socket.emit("msg",{data:name+": "+prompt("Enter your message.")})
}
</script>
<div id="d"></div>`

And this works fine.

Comment: Ok, close now this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FINALLY, I GOT THE SOLUTION ;) :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.3.0/socket.io.js"></script>
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="https://i.ibb.co/sHNyD0b/tecnocomunist-star.png">
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="464161591015-669suu0sat7n9c1lq2g6b3mn174g5sej.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<div style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px"class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn"></div>
<script>
k=[]
obj={}
onkeydown=onkeyup=(e)=>{k[e.keyCode]=e.type=="keydown"}
socket=io("http://p2p-server-by-sentifico.herokuapp.com/")
onSignIn=(googleUser)=>{
 c=document.createElement("canvas")
 document.body.style.margin=0
 document.body.appendChild(c)
 ctx=c.getContext("2d")
 profile=googleUser.getBasicProfile()
 console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()) // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
 console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName())
 console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl())
 console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()) // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
 emailID=profile.getId()
 username=profile.getName()
 imgURL=profile.getImageUrl()
 x=Math.floor(Math.random()*10-5)*128
 y=Math.floor(Math.random()*10-5)*128
 render=()=>{
  requestAnimationFrame(render)
  c.width=innerWidth
  c.height=innerHeight
  socket.emit("msg",{
   data:{
    id:emailID,
    username:username,
    imgURL:imgURL,
    x:x,y:y
   }
  })
  if(k[37]){x-=5}
  if(k[38]){y-=5}
  if(k[39]){x+=5}
  if(k[40]){y+=5}
  for(x2=Math.floor((x-32*40)/32)*32-x+innerWidth/2-16;x2<innerWidth;x2+=32){
   for(y2=Math.floor((y-32*40)/32)*32-y+innerHeight/2-16;y2<innerHeight;y2+=32){
    ctx.lineWidth=4
    ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(200,200,200,1)"
    ctx.strokeRect(x2,y2,32,32)
   }
  }
  for(i in obj){
   img=document.createElement("img")
   img.src=obj[i].imgURL
   ctx.drawImage(img,obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2-64-16,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2-64-16,128,128)
   ctx.lineWidth=4
   ctx.strokeStyle="rgba(0,0,0,1)"
   ctx.strokeRect(obj[i].x-x+innerWidth/2-64-16,obj[i].y-y+innerHeight/2-64-16,128,128)
  }
 }

 render()

 socket.on("msg",(e)=>{
   obj[e.data.id]={
    username:e.data.username,
    imgURL:e.data.imgURL,
    x:e.data.x,y:e.data.y
   }
 })
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If we go on the website and analyze the error, it tells us that the error is in `index.js` at line `50`.

At this line, we have `img.src=obj[i].imgURL` and... there we are.

I typed `obj` in the console and it returned me

```
{
undefined:
username: undefined
imgURL: undefined
x: undefined
y: undefined
}
```

So there is the problem : obj[i] appears to be undefined. As you're defining it at line 60 on a socket receiver, the problem should be server part and not client part.

**EDIT** : Just created another receiver for socket.on('msg'). It appears again to be server side, as the server is sending us an input without anything...

But, try using this code server-side:

```
socket.on('msg', function(message) {
socket.emit('msg', {username: message.username, imgURL: message.imgURL, x: message.x, y: message.y})
})
```

And it should work!

Comment: No, because this works with the same server: http://laboratory.surge.sh/chat.htm

Comment: @DrWerenverlivitz just edited my answer, hope it could help you.